# Анимация icon в ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-animation

Как анимировать `icon` при нажатии?

Так я получаю это самое меню:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

В меня есть `Activity`, в которой есть выездное меню. 
Есть переписаный метод, который срабатывает при нажатии кнопки, как добавить возможность анимировать её? А именно покрутить её на 360 градусов.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerLayout.isShown())
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    else
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

XML разметка, в которой описана эта кнопка:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Меню"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_circle">
</item>
```

Превью: [image: Выглядит так]

И есть описание анимации поворота (возможно неправильно).

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="10000"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### custom_icon.xml

```
<ImageView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="Найти"
android:src="@drawable/icon_search" />
```

### menu_main.xml

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings"
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

### rotate_icon.xml

Анимация как у Вас, только изменен интерполятор и duration.

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:duration="500"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/overshoot"/>
```

### MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    iv = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_icon, null);

    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_icon);
            iv.startAnimation(rotation);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "find is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setActionView(iv);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Вместо иконки появились 3 точки, 
в menu_main.xml
app:showAsAction="always"

Answer (score 1):

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha); 
item.startAnimation(animation);
```

где item - это ваш кнопка

Comment: item в menu это не ViewClass у него нет метода, startAnimation. Здесь нужно пилить кастомный элемент, там целая последовательность.

Comment: item.getActionView().startAnimation

Comment: тогда выдаст ошибку обработки null, я думаю даже если проставить в xml ActionView, то полсе этого выдаст ошибку, тут нарушим цикл создания. Я думаю знаю как сделать, сейчас напишу ответ.

Comment: действительно null выдает. Я обычно не использую стандартный ActionBar, а использую свой. AppBarLayout в котором помещен v7.widget.Toolbar. Если в v7.widget.Toolbar добавить ваше меню, тогда без проблем можете использовать startAnimation. Если нужно могу написать пример использования.

Comment: Да всё верно, в таком случае будет работать и это правильно, не зря ToolBar пришел на замену)) я уже готовлю ответ, у меня получилось сделать, как я и задумывал

Comment: был рад помочь) если нужно будет скину пример. К примеру я исполузую актуальную гамбургер анимацию (когда при нажатии на меню, кнопка трансформируется в стрелку).