# Настройка меню в android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu

Использую ToolBar и на нем эсть кнопка меню  в виде  трех точек! 
Мне нужно заменить ее на свое изображение ... Но я не знаю как !

Прошу подсказки:  как это можно сделать ???

Или можно настроить так чтоб точки были другим цветом ???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/490482/191270 может будет интересно, там кастомная иконка и даже с анимацией простой)))

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, Спасибо !!!
а можно, костомизировать еще и само окно в котором открывается меню, то есть задать цвет фона и тд ? Настроить шрифт и тд???

Comment: Можно всё, но вопрос интересный. Я помню что пришлось popupWindow делать вместо меню, для красивого эффекта и красивой менюшки, а значит не нашел прямой кастомизации. Попробуйте оформить вопрос как новый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы заменить на свое изображение:

```
<style name="Ваша Тема" parent="Тема, я твой отец">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_icon_for_overflow</item>
</style>
```

Если хотите изменить цвет:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar" />

<style name="ThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: спасибо. Изображение меняется , а цвет почему то нет

Comment: а можно, костомизировать еще и само окно в котором открывается меню, то есть задать цвет фона и тд ?

Comment: @Vitaliy, можно, в `xml` прописываете `android:background="цвет"` для `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: я имею ввиду цвет трех точек меню )